# iOS 14 save photo in .limited auth status

Tags: ios, swift

my Photo app has serious problems with the new privacy photo features in iOS 14 and I try to get it to work with .limited access. Because the informations are rare I hope someone can point me in to the right direction.

First of all I use an ImagePicker, my own, because I need to filter PHAsssets on different criteria. Then I pass the assets to my ImagePicker and it only list these. Second it shows an action button to start camera to take a new photo. I think the new PHPickerViewController still don't have these functionalities?!

So its all about the .limited access status - with .authorized access everything is working fine!
I successfully receive a new taken photo from the picker. But it fails saving it to my own created album. First I create the album via

```
let createAlbumRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: AlbumName)
```

which is successful. Next I prepare to add the picture by getting the PHAssetCollection object of this album via

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", AlbumName)
let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
```

Next I would try to save the image to this collection via

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: uiImage)
let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: collection)
...
```

which is not working because the collection object of before is nil. So I can't receive the collection I just created.

I don't know what's the point being allowed to open the camera, create an album, but unable to store things inside?! So I believe I didn't get the new concept :)

Btw I read about a popup which should appear if an app tries to add to collections, which should have pop up in my situation I think, but I never saw such a popup. I know these when deleting from a collection.

Any help appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: If you created the album, you should not need to ask for it by title. That was always an incorrect way to access it.

Comment: You are right. But while debugging this I already tried to take the localIdentifier of createAlbumRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection to pass it to fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers:options:). The fetchResult is still nil.

Comment: Then file a bug with Apple, because they claim that with limited authorization you can access an album that you yourself have created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your album is not created in this case (you can check it in Albums list on your device).
I've created radar for it as a suggestion (to make album creation possible and grant access to created albums as Apple does for photos).

Also you can check: you get `Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7` as error in `performChanges` completion.

So albums currently have different behavior and you can't create them with `.addOnly` access.